# What does linear time series refer to?

Tags: time-series, definition

In some papers or documents, "linear times series" seems to refer to a time series that can be modeled as a linear AR (auto-regressive) model.

In other places, "linear time series" seems to refer to a time series with a linear trend.

When someone just drops "linear time series" out of the blue without any context, what do they mean usually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard the term apply to your second case. I take "linear time series" to mean a time series of the form 
$$
X_t = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_i Z_{t-i},
$$
where $\{Z_t\}$ is a white noise process, and $\{\psi_i\}_i$ are absolutely summable components (i.e. $\sum_i |\psi_i| < \infty$).