# What is the difference between linear and non-linear time series?

Tags: time-series

What do they look like? Is the definition of linearity in time series the same as the linearity in linear regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear time series is one where, for each data point $X_t$, that data point can be viewed as a linear combination of past or future values or differences.  For example, for things that change slowly (the height of a river measured every hour if there isn't a flash flood), next hour's measurement is almost certainly very close to the prior ones, and so on, so you might have a model like this:

$$ x_t = .9x_{t-1}+.81X_{t-2}+...+\epsilon_t $$

This generally gives rise to autocorrelation.  The danger with autocorrelation is that if you don't adjust for it you get regressions that are too good to be true.

Generally, linear time series are modeled as either Autoregressive or Moving Average models, which, combined, become an ARIMA process.  See: https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching673/linear.pdf

A non-linear time series would be a much more complex beast.  There are a whole host of tools for getting it right with ARIMA processes.  But a non-linear time series could be very messy. You might want to take a look also at GARCH series, where the variance wnaders around.

Comment: I saw this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344338/what-does-linear-time-series-refer-to and the answer has a different definition. i am a beginner in time series. Is that definition the same as yours?

Comment: And another thing please. Can i recognize if a time series is linear or not based on it's Plot?

Comment: Yes, the other post got it right...but the more complex answer.  Yes and no to 'can you see it from its plot?'  Imagine plotting the peak temperature each day for a given location.  It will, in fact, not look linear: it will be hottest in summer and coldest in winter.  But, what will make it look 'linear', in the technical sense, is that the temperature on any given day will be most heavily influenced/determined by the temperature in the prior 10-20 days.  This is a whole field of econometrics, and you will need to dig in.